# How can I remove the shadow of a ToolStripMenuItem?

Tags: c#, winforms, menuitem, shadow, toolstripmenu

I am currently creating a menu-bar for my program. My problem is that the drop-down creates a shadow as you can see here.

[image]

I would like to have a flat appearance for my drop-down but there is no attribute for this as far as I know so I am also happy with just removing the shadow which would make it look more flat. I have tried several things already which I have found but they were not very helpful. So how am I able to remove the Shadow.

Comment: WinForms or WPF?

Comment: you can try out this https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12204/Flat-style-Menu-Bar-and-Popup-Menu-Control-for-Win

Comment: `fileToolStripMenuItem.DropDown.DropShadowEnabled = false;`

Comment: @Selvin as written in the first line "windows forms" so winforms ;)

Comment: @LarsTech thank you very much :D